# Parameters in RMI methods

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

Can anyone explain what happens when an object is passed as a parameter in a remote method, while this object does not implement Serializable. Will this method call work ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. All parameters for RMI calls must be `Serializable` so that they can be passed between VMs.

As a thought experiment, what do you think would happen when the VM encountered a non-serializable parameter? How would it properly complete the call?

Comment: Well I guess it would raise an exception. But I had a doubt, since Eclipse gave me no warning.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't know. Serializability is only detected at runtime when you try it. What syntax or semantic rule exactly do you think eclipse should have warned about?

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense. Thanks !